# SwiftUI - @Binding to a computed property which accesses value inside ObservableObject property duplicates the variable?

Tags: mvvm, binding, swiftui, observableobject

In the code below (a stripped-down version of some code in a project) I'm using a MVVM pattern with two views:

- ViewA - displays a value stored in an ObservableObject ViewModel;
- ViewB - displays the same value and has a Slider that changes that value, which is passed to the view using Binding.

Inside of ViewModelA I have a computed property which serves both to avoid the View from accessing the Model directly and to perform some other operations when the value inside the model (the one being displayed) is changed.
 
I'm also passing that computed value to a ViewModelB, using Binding, which acts as a StateObject for ViewB. However, when dragging the Slider to change that value, the value changes on ViewA but doesn't change on ViewB and the slider itself doesn't slide. As expected, when debugging, the wrappedValue inside the Binding is not changing. 
But how is the change propagated upwards (through the Binding's setters, I imagine) but not downwards back to ViewB?? 
I imagine this can only happen if the variable is being duplicated somewhere and changed only in one place, but I can't seem to understand where or if that's what's actually happening.

Thanks in advance!

Views:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModelA = ViewModelA()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ViewA(value: viewModelA.value)
            
            ViewB(value: $viewModelA.value)
        }
    }
}

struct ViewA: View {
    let value: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(value)").padding()
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    @StateObject var viewModelB: ViewModelB
    
    init(value: Binding<Double>){
        _viewModelB = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModelB(value: value))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("\(viewModelB.value)")
            
            Slider(value: $viewModelB.value, in: 0...1)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModels:

```
class ViewModelA: ObservableObject {
    @Published var model = Model()
    
    var value: Double {
        get {
            model.value
        }
        set {
            model.value = newValue
            // perform other checks and operations
        }
    }
}

class ViewModelB: ObservableObject {
    @Binding var value: Double
    
    init(value: Binding<Double>){
        self._value = value
    }
}
```

Model:

```
struct Model {
    var value: Double = 0
}
```

Comment: You generally don't use bindings inside view models. A binding is used for value-type properties of the view.

Comment: Yes, I've never seen anyone using Binding inside ViewModels, but if I stick with mvvm in which the connection between View and Model should be made through the ViewModel, so if I want to change a value stored in a Model with information used throughout an application with, for example, a slider, the only options I see are either using only one ViewModel per Model, or having to pass the Model (or it's properties) between ViewModels through Binding (and I don't see why not). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Binding was meant for something else, so you're not using it correctly. The best practice is to reduce the role of a view to a single job. If you need to change a single model in multiple places, you can use `@EnvironmentObject` to "inject" it, or you can instantiate the view with its view model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you only look where you can't go, you might just miss the riches below

Breaking single source of truth, and breaching local (private) property of `@StateObject`by sharing it via Binding are two places where you can't go.

`@EnvironmentObject` or more generally the concept of "shared object" between views are the riches below.

This is an example of doing it without MVVM nonsense:

```
import SwiftUI

final class EnvState: ObservableObject {@Published var value: Double = 0 }

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var eos: EnvState 

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ViewA()
    
            ViewB()
        }
    }
}

struct ViewA: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var eos: EnvState 

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(eos.value)").padding()
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var eos: EnvState 

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("\(eos.value)")
        
            Slider(value: $eos.value, in: 0...1)
        }
    }
}
```

Isn't this easier to read, cleaner, less error-prone, with fewer overheads, and without serious violation of fundamental coding principles?

MVVM does not take value type into consideration. And the reason Swift introduces value type is so that you don't pass shared mutable references and create all kinds of bugs.

Yet the first thing MVVM devs do is to introduce shared mutable references for every view and pass references around via binding...

Now to your question:

> the only options I see are either using only one ViewModel per Model, or having to pass the Model (or it's properties) between ViewModels through Binding

Another option is to drop MVVM, get rid of all view models, and use `@EnvironmentObject` instead.

Or if you don't want to drop MVVM, pass `@ObservedObject` (your view model being a reference type) instead of `@Binding`.

E.g.;

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModelA = ViewModelA()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ViewA(value: viewModelA)

            ViewB(value: viewModelA)
        }
    }
}
```

On a side note, what's the point of "don't access model directly from view"?

It makes zero sense when your model is value type.

Especially when you pass view model reference around like cookies in a party so everyone can have it.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. It's just everywhere you look online for app architectures/design patterns for SwiftUI everyone seems to think mvvm is the way to go, but after messing with it for a few months I'm starting to get convinced it's actually not close to ideal for apps a bit more complex than the sample ones in tutorials/articles. Which, considering from a deign perspective that apps' UI (especially mobile) should be as simple as possible, kinda makes sense, but as you said, because of Swift's value types, it gets complicated to move information around when the app is a bit more complex.

Comment: Your EnvState is an example of ViewModel, you've just changed hierarchy and the way VM is injected. So not sure what "MVVM nonsense" is about

Answer (score 0):

Really it looks like broken *single-source or truth* concept. Instead the following just works (`ViewModelB` might probably be needed for something, but not for this case)

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

Only modified parts:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModelA = ViewModelA()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ViewA(value: viewModelA.value)

            ViewB(value: $viewModelA.model.value)
        }
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    @Binding var value: Double

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("\(value)")

            Slider(value: $value, in: 0...1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah definitely broken single source of truth I just don't know why. And yes, I've never seen anyone using Binding inside ViewModels, but if I stick with mvvm in which the connection between View and Model should be made through the ViewModel, so if I want to change a value stored in a Model with information used throughout an application with, for example, a slider, the only options I see are either using only one ViewModel per Model, or having to pass the Model (or it's properties) between ViewModels through Binding (and I don't see why not). Or am I missing something?